# Call method of derived class

Tags: c++, list, class

I'm doing a program that manages a collection of items. That can be a Book, a Magazine, a CD or a DVD. Each of those is a class thats inherits the class Item. To store those items I'm  using the list template, like this:

```
list<Item> items;
```

and this list is inside an object lib of the class Library.

To run through this list I'm doing this:

```
for(list<Item>::iterator i = lib.itens.begin(); i != lib.itens.end(); ++i)
```

Until this point everything's fine. The problem starts when I try to call a method of the derived class inside this loop. example:

```
    for(list<Item>::iterator i = lib.itens.begin(); i != lib.itens.end(); ++i)
        (*i).lib.itens.show();
```

How can I call those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems here.  Firstly, if you do this:

```
list<Item> items;
```

then this list really will only contain `Item` objects; if you try to put in a derived object, the derived part will simply be [sliced off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

One solution is to use a list of pointers instead (although you should probably use smart pointers to avoid memory-management issues).

But even then, the second issue is that you shouldn't (in general) be trying to call derived-class-specific methods via pointers to the base class.  The whole point of polymorphism is that you should only be dealing in terms of base-class pointers if you're happy to work with functionality that's common to the whole hierarchy (see [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: ok, and how can I do a list that's able to store objects of any derived classes?

Comment: You need to use list<Item&> instead of list<Item>. References are polymorphic.

Comment: and how to access those items? and add items to the list?

Comment: @carleeto: References are polymorphic, but not objects. Since `list` can only contain objects, you can't create a `list<T&>`. That's why Oli suggested a list of pointers: pointers are both polymorphic and objects.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have defined `virtual void show() = 0;` in `class Item`. That would have made the `show` call legal, but at the same time would have resulted in an error on `list<Item>`.

The fundamental error is that you can't have something that's "just" an `Item`, yet `list<Item>` would attempt to make a list of precisely that. By declaring `show` as a pure virtual function in `Item`, the compiler explicitly knows this.